# Proguard Files for Library project and Application Project

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, android-proguard

I am using a third party .aar project and they have enabled the proguard in the aar project. And in my Application Project i am enabling Proguard as well and its giving me errors.

So, do i need their(.aar project) proguard rules to be included in my proguard config files or is there any other possibility?

I have read in blogs and posts that the best approach is to include the .aar project without proguard and then run the proguard on aar and application project as a whole.

If i run proguard on Application will it affect the imported library's(already proguarded) code ?

Answer (score 1):

> So, do i need their(.aar project) proguard rules to be included in my proguard config files or is there any other possibility?

Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#Considerations):

> You can enable code shrinking on your library by adding a ProGuard configuration file to your library that includes its ProGuard directives. The build tools embed this file within the generated AAR file for the library module. When you add the library to an app module, the library's ProGuard file gets appended to the ProGuard configuration file (proguard.txt) of the app module.

So, if the library module has `consumerProguardFiles 'lib-proguard-rules.txt'` in its `defaultConfig` (see the docs), in principle, those rules will get applied automatically.

> I have read in blogs and posts that the best approach is to include the .aar project without proguard and then run the proguard on aar and application project as a whole.

AFAIK, that's the typical plan. So, the AAR is left alone, with ProGuard applied on the app.

> If i run proguard on Application will it affect the imported library's(already proguarded) code ?

AFAIK, the library's code should not be run through ProGuard.

Comment: So, can i conclude that i dont need the library module proguard rules to be included in my application proguard file?

Comment: @AmanVerma: If your AAR file is set up in the way that the documentation recommends (with `consumerProguardFiles`) *and* you are on a fairly recent `buildToolsVersion` (as I forget when `consumerProguardFiles` was added), then you should not need to duplicate the ProGuard rules from the AAR in the app module's rules. That being said, since Android Studio now has that lovely APK Analyzer, you might examine the results of the `release` build and confirm that ProGuard did remove/obfuscate what you would expect from the library. IOW, "trust, but verify". :-)

Comment: After hours of digging, I had to include the AAR proguard rules in the App's proguard files and it is working fine. Perhaps the AAR wasn't properly proguarded. Thanks for the much elaborated answer.