# As a library developer: how to avoid the user's Proguard

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard, minify, android-r8

I'm a library developer.

I'm experiencing issues with the users of my library regarding Proguard. Seems like their Proguard is messing the models of the library.

I have defined in the `proguard-rules.pro` file of the library, which are the packages and classes I don't want to shrink, as the following:

```
-keep class com.x.library.data.models.** {*;}
```

Seems like their Proguard shrinks everything anyways.

Is there a way to avoid their Proguard to shrink the library I develop?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can let the developers who integrate your library add rules in their proguard file that keep your classes. I.E. ```-keep class your.package.name.**```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `consumerProguardFiles` in your library `defaultConfig` to specify a Proguard rules file that will get merged with the one in the app.

See also the following questions:

- [How to use ProGuard in Library Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44069851/how-to-use-proguard-in-library-module)
- [Proguard Files for Library project and Application Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43969160/proguard-files-for-library-project-and-application-project)